# eof() function not working c++ stuck with infinite loop

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, eof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

im having a problem with the eof() function. my loop is not reading the end of the file that im reading from thus leaving me with an infinite loop. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. thanks

```
 while (!file2.eof()) {

    getline (file2, title, ','); 
    getline (file2, authorf, ',');
    getline (file2, authorl, ',');
    getline (file2, isbn, ',');
    file2 >> pages;
    file2.ignore();
    file2 >> price;
    file2.ignore();
    getline(file2, subject, ',');
    file2 >> code;
    file1.ignore();
    file2 >> rentalp;
    file2.ignore(10, '\n');


    textbook b2(title, authorf, authorl, publisher, pages, isbn, price, code, subject, rentalp);
    b2.PrintTbook();
    TbookList[j] = b2; //initalizing the first element of the array to b2.
    newFile << "Title: " << TbookList[j].getTitle() << "\n" << "Price: " << TbookList[j].getPrice() << "\n\n";
    TbookList[j].PrintBook();
    j++;
    textbookCount++;
}
```

the text file looks like this:

A Practical Introduction to Data Structures and Algorithim Analysis, Clifford, Shaffer,  0-13-028446-7, 512, 90.00, Computer Science, E, 12.00, 2001
Fundamentals of Database Systems, Ramez, AlMasri, 9-780805-317558, 955, 115.50, Computer Science, E,  0.0, 2003

Comment: Can you show a sample of the data format?

Comment: The reason is simple: a read fails, `file2.good()` will be false and all the subsequent read attempts will fail, but `eof()` will still be false as well, and you get in an infinite loop.

Comment: Try this: `while(true) { /* get input */ if(!file2) break; /* use input data */ }`

Comment: @SethCarnegie One of the reasons I usually use "file.good()" since it checks ALL conditions rather than just the 1.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I just added the text file to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, almost any loop of the form `while (!whatever.eof())` is completely broken.

Second, you have what I'm going to assume is a typo:

```
file1.ignore();
```

The rest of the code is reading from `file2`, so I'm going to guess `file1` is just a typo here (but if you've copied it correctly, it could be the real source of a problem).

You usually want to do things like this by overloading `operator>>` for the type you're reading:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, textbook &b2) {
    getline (is, title, ','); 
    getline (is, authorf, ',');
    getline (is, authorl, ',');
    getline (is, isbn, ',');
    is>> pages;
    is.ignore();
    is>> price;
    is.ignore();
    getline(is, subject, ',');
    is>> code;
    is.ignore();
    is>> rentalp;
    is.ignore(10, '\n');
    return is;
}
```

Then you can read in a bunch of objects something like:

```
std::vector<textbook> books;

textbook temp;

while (file2>>temp) {
    books.push_back(temp);
    temp.printbook();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Your right the typo was the cause of the infinite loop THANKS. I would love to use this alternative way of reading objects but im new to this and arent familer with vectors yet, but ill do some reading up on it